# How to remove the last number 0 in the fibonacci series in c++?

Tags: c++

I m trying to remove the last 0 in the fibonacci series

as i m removing return 0; the last value is showing garbage value

something like 735150

what should i edit to get the desired output as

0 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181

as i m getting the output

0 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 0

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fibo
{
private:

unsigned long int n1,n2,final;

public:
fibo()
{
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 1;
    final = n1 + n2;
}

fibo(int x1,int x2) //Parameterised Constructor
{
    n1 = x1;
    n2 = x2;
    for (int x = 0;x<=8; x++)
    {
        final = n1 + n2;
        cout << final << " ";
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = final;
    }
    
}

int calc()
{
    for (int x = 0;x<=8; x++)
    {
        final = n1 + n2;
        cout << final << " ";
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = final;
    }
    return 0;
}

fibo(fibo &i); // Copy Constructor
};

fibo::fibo(fibo &i)
{
n1= i.n1;
n2 = i.n2;
final = i.final;
}

int main()
{
cout << "0 " ;
fibo f1(0,1);
fibo f2 = f1;

cout << f2.calc() << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does `calc` return `0` _and why do you print it_?

Comment: i used it as a workaround as the  output was not coming using the copy constructor so i created calc function

Comment: Isn't the fibonnacci series 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ? I'm pretty sure a rabbit can't fornicate with itself.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe It looks like `main` prints the first `0`, then the constructor prints the _second_ `1` and then eight more digits, then `calc` prints nine more digits. This seems like a very bizarre way to handle this functionality.

Comment: i seen other fibonacci programs so thought of putting 0 in the start

Comment: could u share a more easy approach @NathanPierson

Comment: as i was given question like this in my class                                                                
Write a program to generate a series of Fibonacci numbers using copy constructor, where it is defined outside the class using scope resolution operator?

Comment: How about not bothering with a class at all and just having a `fibo` free function that takes the two starting values and the number of digits to print and just calling that? EDIT: Oh. The bizarre architecture decisions are imposed by an assignment. Well, that explains that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm perfectly aware this isn't code review but OP asked for a simpler version.

This is not conforming to the odd copy constructor requirement, but rather to show that printing the fibonacci numbers can be dealt with in a few(8) lines of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// This is a poor time to use a classes and objects,
// This is simply a straightforward algorithm.
// calculation is not an object
// As Nathan says, it is a bizarre design

// Generate numbers
std::vector<int> fibonacci_numbers(int N){
    auto n0 = 0; // not used in output
    auto n1 = 1; // first value in output
    auto next_fib = [&n0,&n1](){
        auto value = n1;
        auto next = n0 + n1;
        n0 = n1;
        n1 = next;
        return value;
    };
    auto result = std::vector<int>(N);
    std::generate(result.begin(), result.end(), next_fib);
    return result;
}

// Print
void print_fibo(int N){
    int n0 = 0; // not for printing
    int n1 = 1;
    while(N--){
        auto next_fib = n0 + n1;
        std::cout << n1 << ", ";
        n0 = n1;
        n1 = next_fib;
    }
}

int main() {
    // seems like you want 19 numbers
    // generating
    auto fibs = fibonacci_numbers(9);
    for(auto e:fibs){
        std::cout << e << ", ";
    }
    // just printing
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_fibo(19);
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes as shown in the [below](https://onlinegdb.com/-KtOwdc0S) code. First you don't need to create a copy of the object f1. You can just directly call `f1.calc()`. Second `calc`'s return type is changed to void. Third, constructor initializer list is used. You can check the working program [here](https://onlinegdb.com/-KtOwdc0S).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fibo
{
private:

unsigned long int n1,n2,final;

public:
//use constructor initializer list
fibo(): n1(0), n2(1), final(n1+n2)
{
    //n1 = 0;
    //n2 = 1;
    //final = n1 + n2;
}

fibo(int x1,int x2) //Parameterised Constructor
{
    n1 = x1;
    n2 = x2;
    for (int x = 0;x<=8; x++)
    {
        final = n1 + n2;
        cout << final << " ";
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = final;
    }
    
}

void calc()
{
    for (int x = 0;x<=8; x++)
    {
        final = n1 + n2;
        cout << final << " ";
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = final;
    }
    //no need to return
    //return 0;
}

fibo(fibo &i); // Copy Constructor
};

fibo::fibo(fibo &i)
{
n1= i.n1;
n2 = i.n2;
final = i.final;
}

int main()
{
cout << "0 1 " ;
fibo f1(0,1);

//no need to create new object
//fibo f2 = f1;

//call f1.calc() instead of f2.calc()
f1.calc();

 return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181
```

Note there are other ways to implement this. You can check out these [here](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/fibonacci-series).

Also, in your given example code output, the starting 3 numbers should be 0 1 1 instead of 0 1 2. You can change `cout << "0 ";` to `cout << "0 1 ";` to get the correct output `0 1 1` as i did in my edit.

Comment: The output is wrong. The Fibonacci sequence starts out with `1 1 2`. If you’re going to start it with 0 it should be `0 1 1 2`. Each element is the sum of the two preceding elements. `0 1 2` doesn’t do that.

Comment: Yeah, i just matched it with the OP's desired output. The only thing we need is to add `1` manually as i did in my edit. Also, i am aware that there are better ways to write the fibonacci sequence but that is not what OP asked.

Comment: @SiddharthPatel In your given example code output, the starting 3 numbers should be `0 1 1` instead of `0 1 2`. You can change `cout << "0 ";` to `cout << "0 1 ";` to get the correct output `0 1 1` as i did in my edit. Also there are other ways to print fibonacci series. Some of them can be found [here](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/fibonacci-series) .

Comment: @AnoopRana — if you have to write out `std::cout << “0 1”` to get the correct output your algorithm is wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker The question was titled "how to remove the last number  0 ..." and it didn't explicitly asked for a new(or better) implementation to print the fibonacci series, so i didn't provide one. I provided what was asked by the OP, namely, the output `0 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181` .

Comment: @SiddharthPatel You're welcome. But next time be specific about what you want. That is, whether you want a better new implementation of your given code or just correct the mistakes(if any) that you've made so that people don't waste time on what you don't need.

Comment: yeah sure buddy